# Pulling information from a Database table php

Tags: java, php, mysql, database

I know this has probably been asked a lot on here, but I am just stumped. I am working for a company with an e-commerce site built on top of java. What I was asked to do today was to pull out basically all the information from the table in a query and then write it to a textfile in a nice clean table layout. I really have no experience with this sort of thing.

Comment: Your question needs work. It seems as though your real question is "How do I create a file suitable for submission to godatafeed.com based on data pulled from a MySQL table?" The godatafeed.com format specs are here: http://www.godatafeed.com/GoDataFeed-Source-File-Specifications.pdf

Comment: Sounds like you need a DB Mgmt Tool of Choice, Build your query there and then export it to Excel? Ask some coworkers about what sql tool is available, Oracle->SQL Developer, Various-> Toad, PostgreSQL -> pgAdmin, ...

Comment: @Asaph Where on Earth did you get the idea that he wanted to use godatafeed.com? He never mentioned a file format or a service provider. Sounds like advertising to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following commandline can be used to dump a MySQL table to a textfile in table format. I have only tried this on linux, but something similar should work on any system with MySQL.

```
echo "SELECT * FROM name_of_table" | mysql -t -u username -h host -p password database > outfile
```